# Data population in jQuery mobile happen before database initialization is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have a Phonegap application. A script that initializes the database is like this

```js
initialize: function () {
    db = window.openDatabase("db_location", "1.0", "Main Db", 1000000);
    db.transaction(app.initDB, app.dbError, app.dbReady);
}
```

and then I will do app.initialize to initiate the database. I have another function that populate the database.

```js
$(document).delegate('#index-page', 'pagebeforeshow', function(){
    PopulateMainLocations();
});
```

**My Problem**
The function to populate the data is happened before the database is finished initializing. I have tried many different approaches and it does not work. What should I do?

Comment: I think you need to use callbacks, can you shoe more code?

Comment: I haven't used the Cordova database plugin* but I think you need to put your 'populate' function in the 'app.dbReady' callback: 'function app.dbReady() {PopulateMainLocations()}'.........*but it could be useful for my project so thanks for reminding me it exists :-)